# How to stop Music from restoring old files after file rename

Tags: itunes, apple-music

So, I have a bunch of music stored on a hard-drive which I use and hook up to Apple Music. I received the Music from someone and it had all sorts of weird song names, for example I CANT IMAGINE (all caps) instead of "I Can't Imagine". So I went through and changed all the file names to be what I wanted (I changed them on the hard drive itself). I then deleted the library, and the library file (but not the music files themselves (with the now up to date names) and reimported the songs to Apple Music. But afterwards the original songs names are there, and when (and only when) I click on Get Info and look at where the file is located, it creates a new folder called Music (within my already existing folder called Music) which only has the song with the old title. It does this for each subsequent song I look at the Get Info for, it adds the old song with the old title to that new folder.

To clarify, it deletes the song with the title changed, and adds a version with the old file name to the new folder Music (all inside my drive). It is really becoming very frustrating. Any ideas as to how to fix this and effectively change the file names? (I have over 900 GB of music, most of it wasn't boughten from iTunes itself, so the best option has been to change the file names' case in bulk, which has worked well except for this phenomenon). I even restarted the computer and have, multiple times, deleted the music library file. I don't use the Media folder on my computer, but instead change it to point to my hard drive as there isn't enough space on my MacBook Air to keep it all on the computer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! (Sorry for the long entry, I wanted to ensure that all bases possible were covered)